# Combining Queries that require three tables SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting

I'm finding it a bit confusing to solve the following questions...

"
An employee may be assigned to more than one project and a project may have many employees. Consider the following relational schema and write SQL statements for the below queries.

```
Employees (empID, empName, empDOB, empAddress, salary, deptID, jobID)

Assignments (empID, projID, assignedDate, completionDate, status)`

Projects (projID, projDescription, startDate, endDate, projType)
```

(a) Display the names of employees who were born before 31st Jan 1980 and assigned a ‘Office Complex’ type project, sort results in ascending order of name.

(b) Retrieve the empIDs who are assigned at least two (2) projects. 
"

My answer so far .

(a) `SELECT empName FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE empDOB < '31-january-1980' AND ....`

"

Please help me out

Comment: You use join between tables (Google that)

Comment: You might find help with your homework, but what will you do at exam time? http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score -1):

try this : 
A)

```
SELECT employee.empName
FROM Assignments ass 
   JOIN Employees employee
      ON employee .empID= ass.empID
   JOIN Projects  project
      ON project.projID= ass .projID
WHERE employee.empDOB < '31-january-1980' 
      AND project.projType = ‘Office Complex’
ORDER BY  employee.empName;
```

Without using `JOIN` CLAUSE

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee.empName
FROM Employees employee
WHERE employee.empDOB < '31-january-1980' 
      AND employee.empID  IN (
           SELECT ass.empID
           FROM Assignments ass
           WHERE ass.projID  IN (
                SELECT project.projID
                FROM  Projects project
                WHERE project.projType = ‘Office Complex’
           )
      )
ORDER BY  employee.empName ASC;
```

b)

```
SELECT ass.empID, COUNT(*) as counting 
FROM Assignments ass
GROUP BY ass.empID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks , But could you tell me .. (b) Retrieve the empIDs who are assigned at least two (2) projects. "

Comment: Hey , they are ok but isnt there a way to do it without using JOIN , i think my lecturer does not want the JOIN Tag used....

Comment: I updated my solution. Don't hesitate to  rate it if it is OK. I hope it will help.